# Workaround for "null primitives" in JDBC PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, nullable

When using raw JDBC, you can parameterize a `PreparedStatement` like so:

```
PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(someSQLString);
String someString = getSomeString();
Integer int = getSomeInteger();
statement.setString(1, someString);
statement.setLong(2, 5L);
statement.setInt(3, int);

...
```

Here, if `someString` is `null`, that's fine - strings are nullable. But if `getSomeInteger()` returns `null`, we have a problem.

`PreparedStatement#setInt(int,int)` sets a primitive `int` as the value, and therefore cannot be `null`.

**However, it's perfectly plausible that I might want the value of the 3rd column above to be `null` for this particular record.** After all, every RDBMS I've ever worked with allows numeric (INT, LONG, etc.) fields to be NULLABLE...

So what's the workaround?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't use any of those and use [`setObject`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject%28int,%20java.lang.Object%29) instead, let the JDBC driver to manage the `null` values instead of you.

Comment: Thanks @Luiggi Mendoza (+1) - can you confirm that `setObject` handles all types, and handles when any type is NULL? Basically, does it cover all scenarios? Any caveats or pitfalls to watch out for? Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja this will depend on the JDBC driver. Note the last part of the `setObject` documentation: ***Note:** Not all databases allow for a non-typed Null to be sent to the backend. For maximum portability, the setNull or the setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x, int sqlType) method should be used instead of setObject(int parameterIndex, Object x)*. I recommend doing some tests and then use the best method for your case.

Comment: OK - thanks again @Luiggi Mendoza (+1) - last followup: would `setObject(int,Object,int)` cover all types, null and non-null alike? It sound like that's the one I want...in other words: am I guaranteed that this method correctly handles all types and nulls in all/most JDBC drivers?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja again, this depends on the JDBC driver. Do some tests (because you never stated which JDBC driver you use) and then decide if you should use `setObject` or `setNull` instead.

Comment: if `setObject`  is more suitable I don't understand why we let `setTYPE`  methods in PreparedStatement. 
Should we expect them to be deprecated in the near future ?

Comment: @soung those methods let you add primitives. In Java, primitive types must have a value, they can't be `null`. Thus you should use `setObject` or `setNull`

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) method of the `PreparedStatement` class.

Here's an example of how to use it:

```
  String query = 
     "insert into nullable_table(id,string_column, int_column) values(?, ?, ?)";

  // create PrepareStatement object
  PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
  pstmt.setString(1, id);
  pstmt.setNull(2, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR);
  pstmt.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
```

Example taken from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/DemoPreparedStatementSetNullforintvaluecolumn.htm).

Comment: Thanks @kocko (+1) - please read my question underneath Luiggi's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks!  I was googling this for 15 minutes and your post was the clearest and most concise!

Comment: What is the correct SQL type for long?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [setNull()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull%28int,%20int%29) method. Based on parameter is `null` or not check you need to either call `setNull()` (or) `setInt()`.

Comment: Thanks @Nambari (+1) - please read my question underneath Luiggi's answer - I have the same question for you! Thanks again!

Comment: @IAmYourFaja: As Luggin commented, if you use setObject, you are sticking to database driver implementation, if other doesn't support you will end up changing your code. If I have to decide, I wouldn't go with setObject() approach (assuming we don't know which databases we will use as we go). I would be happy to add few lines of code.